# Limit odhcpd SLAAC / RA to specific MAC addresses

Tags: router, ipv6, openwrt

I am trying to set up my OpenWRT powered router to give me IPv6 connectivity via tunnelbroker.net (he.net). I am using OpenWrt Chaos Calmer 15.05-rc2.
Creating the tunnel works fine, but I'd like to limit the IPv6 prefix advertisement to a list of devices / MACs.

I did some research, so I learned that my OpenWRT version uses *odhcpd* instead of *radvd*. 
Some searches brought up http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/odhcpd and http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/dhcp?s[]=slaac. But both pages do not show any option to limit the advertisement. There is an `limit` option, but it looks like an "all-or-nothing" switch.
As far as I remember, radvd has a feature like this. It accepts a list local links within a list called `clients`.

Last but not least, here is my current */etc/config/dhcp* file:

```
config dnsmasq
    option domainneeded '1'
    option boguspriv '1'
    option filterwin2k '0'
    option localise_queries '1'
    option rebind_protection '1'
    option rebind_localhost '1'
    option local '/lan/'
    option domain 'lan.e-mehlbox.eu'
    option expandhosts '1'
    option nonegcache '0'
    option authoritative '1'
    option readethers '1'
    option leasefile '/tmp/dhcp.leases'
    option resolvfile '/tmp/resolv.conf.auto'
    list server '192.168.1.1'
    list server '8.8.8.8'
    list server '8.8.4.4'

config dhcp 'lan'
    option interface 'lan'
    option start '100'
    option limit '150'
    option leasetime '12h'
    option dhcpv6 'server'
    option ra 'server'

config dhcp 'wan'
    option interface 'wan'
    option ignore '1'

config odhcpd 'odhcpd'
    option maindhcp '0'
    option leasefile '/tmp/hosts/odhcpd'
    option leasetrigger '/usr/sbin/odhcpd-update'
```

Any hints or suggestions?